# Process substitution and cat: can't read stdin

Tags: io-redirection, process-substitution

The process substitution `<(cat)` doesn't work. Why?

```
head <(cat) 
cat: -: Input/output error
```

I can use an extra file descriptor, but I don't understand why the above doesn't work.

```
# Using file descriptor 3 to reroute the input
(head <(cat <&3)) 3<&0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `bash`, if you do:

```
$ cat <(ps -j)
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 3887 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 bash
 3888  3888 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 cat
 3889 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 ps
16480 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 bash
```

In `zsh`:

```
$ cat <(ps -j)
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 3935  3935 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 ps
 3936  3936 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 cat
16480 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 zsh
```

In `ksh93`:

```
$ cat <(ps -j)
  PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
 3946 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 ps
 3947  3947 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 cat
16480 16480 16480 pts/29   00:00:00 ksh
```

In all 3 shells, the `ps` process is in a different process group from `cat`'s one, which is the foreground process group of the terminal. `zsh` at least is nice enough to redirect stdin in there to `/dev/null` if it was a tty to avoid problems with that, like many shells do for commands run in background.

Your command would work OK if stdin was not a terminal, but here, since `cat` is not in the foreground process group of the terminal, it reading from the terminal means it will receive a `SIGTTIN` signal which would cause it to be suspended. And that is not handled gracefully here. In your case, it seems `SIGTTIN` is being ignored or blocked for you to get a EIO error (which you get when trying to read from your controlling terminal when you're not in its foreground process group and ignore/block `SIGTTIN`).

In

```
(head <(cat <&3)) 3<&0
```

however, we're starting a sub-shell in foreground, and all the processes in there end up in that same process group so are allowed to read from the terminal. With the explicit redirection in there, with `zsh`, we're bypassing `zsh`'s redirection from `/dev/null`. With other shells,

```
(head <(cat))
```

would also work.