# Read a password securely from within process substitution?

Tags: bash, pipe, read, fifo, process-substitution

Related:

- [Securely feeding a program with a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78757/135943)
- [How to read from stdin in process substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247775/135943)
- [Process substitution and cat: can't read stdin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244326/135943)

I've read the above questions and I still can't work out how to do what I need.

I have a binary command I'll call `getreport` that does the following:

1. Prompt for a password (prompt sent to stderr)
2. Read the password from stdin.
3. Print extensive data to stdout.

I have another binary command to parse the output from the first command that I'll call `processreport`.  However, it doesn't work with stdin; it will only accept and process a file specified on the command line with a `-i` flag.  It reads from the file, does things with the data it reads in, and outputs data about what it did.  (The `processreport` command can *also* prompt for a password, entirely separately from `getreport`.)

I want to use process substitution to make this possible in a single line, rather than requiring a temp file to hold the output of `getreport`.

Something like:

```
processreport -i <(getreport)
```

However, I don't know how to make `getreport` read in *from the terminal* the password it requires.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
{ getreport | 4<&0 <&3 processreport -i /dev/fd/4; } 3<&0
```

It could be more simple if you're willing always to read explicitly from `/dev/tty`:

```
getreport | 3<&0 </dev/tty processreport -i /dev/fd/3
```

...or more simply still if you know that stderr will always equal stdin - as it typically does in a terminal...

```
getreport | 3<&0 <&2 processreport -i /dev/fd/3
```

Comment: That looks too good to be true thus I would like to point out this: "The processreport command can also prompt for a password, entirely separately from getreport."

Comment: @HaukeLaging - ok, thanks for that - it does complicate matters some, but it doesn't make it *much* more difficult. i overlooked it i guess, but at least it does explain why `processreport` requires a named read file.

Answer (score 2):

`getreport` cannot read from the terminal because it is a background process.

`man 2 read`:

> EIO : I/O  error.
>   This will happen for example when the process is in a background process group, tries to read from its controlling terminal, and either it is ignoring or blocking SIGTTIN or its process group is orphaned.

I guess what you want is not possible without some shell wrapping. But maybe this is closer to what you want:

```
mkfifo fifo; read -p "Input for FIFO: " input; echo "$input">fifo &
cat <(read bginput <fifo; echo "$bginput"); rm fifo
```

This obviously doesn't not work well for wrong passwords and read retries.

```
mkfifo fifo; read -p "Input for FIFO: " input; echo "$input">fifo &
processreport -i <(getreport <fifo); rm fifo
```

Comment: Could you please edit your example to use my made-up commands `processreport` and `getreport`?  With the way you have it written currently using `cat` and `echo`, I can't tell where they're supposed to be dropped in.

Comment: @Wildcard Done.

Comment: why bother using process substitution if you're gonna make a fifo?